# Why I can't access iframe on same domain with common approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( "a" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>
```

From JQ docs.

May be problem is that I do it on localhost?

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#sample_test').contents().find('a').css('color', 'red')
    })

</script>
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/tests/384"  width="100%" seamless="seamless"  height="1150px" scrolling="no" id="sample_test"></iframe>
```

Doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: What is the domain of the parent window

Comment: @putvande, both main page and iframe are on localhost

Comment: It might also be that your iframe is not ready yet when you try to change the color. Try wrap it in setTimeout and see what happens or add an 'onload' to the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an `onload` event to the iframe in order to do that. The iframe might nog be fully loaded yet when the `document.ready` is called.

But this will only work if the source in the iframe is from the same domain.